# Can't locate ISO for Lubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I hope this is the correct use of this forum - I am a long term Lubuntu user, and attempting to move to 20.04.

I am seeking the LTS version of Lubuntu, 20.04.1, with kernel 5.4, which is supported for 5 years.

I recently downloaded the latest Lubuntu Desktop from here: https://lubuntu.me/downloads/
which provides the latest Point Release, which is Lubuntu 20.04.2. It came with kernel 5.8, which is only supported for 9 months.
.
The above web page also offered a link to download previous versions: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/

Unfortunately, that second link only serves up Lubuntu 20.04.2, no matter what directory you choose. I went to here for example: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04.1/release/
but it too only offers 20.04.2.

I am wondering if anyone can assist. Is it still possible to obtain an ISO for Lubuntu Desktop 20.04.1? Or should I just install 20.04.2 and manually downgrade the kernel (I suspect that might not be safe).
.
Appreciate assistance if anyone knows. Perhaps https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04.1/release/
is mistakenly offering the wrong version?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I can't find 20.04.1 on ubuntu release mirrors. The easier is to install 20.04.2 and downgrade the kernel.

Comment: I am a big fan of sudodus' image files as offered below. You can install it to USB using Rufus, Win32DiskImager, Etcher, mkusb, dd, Disks, etc.

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463290

Answer (score 7):

## Edit

### The file you want: `lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

As a Lubuntu member, I decided to provide a copy of the Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS iso file, that I know is good, and that I can manage myself.

I downloaded a copy of `lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` when it was recently released (and checked it), so I know that it is good. I uploaded a copy of that iso file plus two checksum files so that you can check your copy after downloading.

**See [this link](https://phillw.net/isos/lubuntu/focal/).**

There is also a file at the Wayback Machine as shown in the answer by muru.

The following paragraphs are kept in the answer as examples of possible work-arounds [for other cases], when you cannot find the file that you want.

## End of edit

---

### Lubuntu 20.04 LTS demo example

You can find a demo example made by me, that might be useful for you.

**See a description and discussion at [this link](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/add-a-menuentry-for-persistence-into-the-default-grub-cfg-and-txt-cfg/1039/4)**

**and a [link to a compressed image (from post #4 in that discussion)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13L40kDjTLvOQ8JGXhrYtc_YHawc23ZIA?usp=sharing).**

This will bring **Lubuntu 20.04 LTS** (uploaded May 1 2020, before the release of 20.04.1 LTS), it has the correct kernel series for you, but after installing, there will be a lot of updates & upgrades.

Warning: The general Ubuntu program packages will be supported for 5 years, but **the specific Lubuntu packages will be supported for only 3 years**. Please notice that all community flavours have only 3 years support of the LTS releases.

### Standard Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Another work-around is to get **standard Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** from

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/

and add Lubuntu

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

There will be 'some extra files' but it might work well, and today drive space is seldom a bottleneck.

### Ubuntu 20.04 mini.iso

Yet another alternative is to start from the Ubuntu 20.04 `mini.iso`. You can find it (dated April 21 2020) via [this link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/) and the md5sum is 'upstairs' in the parent directory.

The installer in `mini.iso` is the old text mode debian installer. You can install `lubuntu-desktop` during or after the installation.

Please notice that `mini.iso` works **only in BIOS mode** (alias CSM alias legacy mode). It does not boot in UEFI mode.

### Downgrading from 20.04.2 to 20.04.1

The following downgrading method was verified by ajgreeny at this

[Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463290&p=14042362#post14042362)

**It is maybe the easiest method**, at least if you have the Lubuntu 20.04.2 iso file already :-)

- Install Lubuntu 20.04.2 from the available iso file
- Boot into the installed Lubuntu system
- Remove the hwe kernel package

  ```
  sudo apt remove linux-generic-hwe-20.04
  ```
- Install the plain kernel package

  ```
  sudo apt install linux-generic
  ```

  It will immediately pull in the most recent 5.4.0-74 kernel plus dependencies, eg the header packages.
- Reboot and remove the unwanted kernel package

  ```
  sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic
  ```

  along with any other versions of the 5.8 series.
- Finally autoremove the now unused packages and maybe also make things up to date and then clean by

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade

  sudo apt autoremove --purge

  sudo apt autoclean
  sudo apt clean
  ```

Answer (score 4):

The Wayback Machine has the original ISO list page from Lubuntu 20.04.1 archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20210128060849/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04.1/release/

In particular, the ISO is available at https://web.archive.org/web/20210128060849/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04.1/release/lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso (*caveat emptor*: I haven't downloaded it or verified it.

Comment: +1; Thanks for this useful link :-)

Comment: The **sha256sum** of `lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` at Wayback matches that of my file, downloaded from the official Ubuntu web site when the file was quite fresh, so you can use it to verify the iso file after downloading.

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend reading sudodus' answer (*if you look he's a* [*Lubuntu member*](https://launchpad.net/%7Elubuntu-members))

For years I downloaded all and store them on my local server (*Canonical commonly don't keep flavors beyond the latest ISO*), but when I've needed an ISO that I don't have locally, I've almost always found it on an official mirror (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) having had the best luck with French & German Ubuntu LoCo (forum) sites (*though I always use another site to get the checksum to validate it if I don't already have it locally, and it's not quick as I don't read either French or German*).

*Sorry I'm not on my normal PC so I don't have access to my history where I'd likely be able to provide a URL that maybe helpful, but I fear it was a 18.04.3 or old bionic ISO so won't be what you're after anyway*

**Lubuntu 20.04.2 and switching to GA stack**

I will add that I've tested starting with a Lubuntu 20.04.2 ISO, installing it, then adding the GA kernel stack to it. You can follow the instructions found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack in the *DESKTOP* section and they work...

Removing the HWE stack is *optional*, so I'd not do it until you know the GA stack is perfectly functional (*keeping it will just cost more packages installed; ie. disk space used, more packages to update; ie. bandwidth for updates, ie. minimal effects*) but the wiki makes that clear as it suggests only removing packages "*if everything is good*".

(*I may not have tested all commands exactly as listed in the Ubuntu wiki, eg. Lubuntu media does **not** include OEM support so I'd likely have skipped those packages, I documented it somewhere (likely on Lubuntu's discourse too), but sorry I'm not looking for it as I'm not on my PC and may not be there in a few days*).

Comment: This is really a really long comment

Comment: I've already made reference to @sudodus' answer;  I've added the link (he provided) to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXDE-lubuntu/Alternate_ISO  (*LXDE-lubuntu is how LXDE pages of Lubuntu are now stored*).. the caveat I think is necessary (it's a 3rd party site) even if care is made ensuring legitimate ISOs go to the site.  Thanks Sudodus & Phill.  The page is about 18.04 yes, but the 20.04.1 ISO is still there  (refer to Sudodus' answer for all details though)

Comment: Thankyou kindly for all of your help, I now have the ISO image.
SUDODUS - thanks for the kernel downgrade instructions. I did previously test this on a VM, but I was nervous about "missing something". The last few steps you provided solve that, thanks very much. 
MURU - the Wayback Machine is very useful, that is where I got the image, thankyou. GUIVERC - Appreciate your info on the GA stack - I need to do some reading before I understand it fully. AND FINALLY: Apologies, I did ask the same question on the Ubuntu Forum - now that I see how things work, I will avoid that in the future.