# Where do I find previous 18.04 point releases?

Tags: downloads, release-management

Where are the version of 18.04 LTS prior to 5 found? We have an application that stopped working on 18.04.5 and want to install 18.04.4 and possibly earlier. They don't seem to be any links to the older versions on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't locate ISO for Lubuntu 20.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344457/cant-locate-iso-for-lubuntu-20-04-1)

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 18.04.6 media should be officially launched in a few hours (*I expect according to schedule*); it's available now (20210915) as I just completed some QA-tests with it

Answer (score 13):

Point releases don't work like that!

Point releases exist because LTS releases are supported for 5 years. We use point releases to consolidate updates so that people installing the release years after the initial release do not have years' worth of updates after system installation.

If you install an older point release, you will still get the same updates and will end up with the same packages as the newer point release because they are the same exact distribution.

See: [What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/106159)

Holding back updates is not a good plan either.  Keeping up with updates is an essential maintenance task unless your device never connects to the internet. Instead of asking how to install an older point release, you should [ask about the actual problem that you experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) in 18.04.5.  There is likely a better solution to your problem!

Comment: Maybe OP is a developer of that software, and he wants to install older releases on a test machine to check what changed and caused it to fail (and exactly which release caused it).

Answer (score 8):

Old releases can be found here:
https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stacks; but you've provided no specifics as to your issue thus this may not help, so rather than installing 18.04.4 which will update to 18.04.5 on first update!, one option maybe to switch to the other kernel stack (*esp. if you're using the HWE stack*).

You're talking about an update that occurred more than a year ago now anyway (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 18.04.5, but installed systems got the update a week+ before that date) so you're missing details most probably and likely blaming the wrong thing.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 using the HWE stack used the kernel from 19.10, ie. the 5.3 kernel.  The upgrade to 18.04.5 with the HWE stack caused it to upgrade to the 20.04 or 5.4 kernel.

If however you were using the GA stack, there was no change, as the GA stack remains on 5.4 and is supported the life of 18.04.

You can view https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for more details on the stack choices offered with Ubuntu LTS (*with 18.04 the ISO used to install your system controlled the default stack; 18.04 & 18.04.1 media defaulted to GA, later media defaulted to HWE*).  If you want to use the GA stack instead of HWE; search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*"

Comment: GA stack remains on the newer version...?  Did you mean 5.3 there?

Comment: Also the linked LTSEnablementStack page is out of date:  18.04.2 and beyond are all vTBD

Comment: vTBD?  The wiki page is correct I believe; if it isn't please correct it or outline the issues so I can correct. The page says "*The 18.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel and X stack by default for the desktop*" ie. the 18.04.6 media I QA-tested yesterday has the HWE stack on it; like that statement says ; ie. there is nothing "*to be decided*" but it fits with documentation; the page was last edited (*which makes it a little less clear*) because *focal* and later don't use the pattern used by 10.04 -> 18.04, but starts a new HWE pattern for Ubuntu Desktop  @Izkata

Comment: There was no change with Ubuntu Server, or Lubuntu (which uses the `calamares` installer; as changes were made only in `ubiquity` or the Ubuntu Desktop installer). The changes allow the installer to decide which kernel to use; ie. GA, HWE or an OEM kernel if it is detected better. The changes made for *focal* (and later) only impact this new feature; but HWE kernel is now default for all installs, not only .2 and later (*focal* and up)  @Izkata

Comment: I'm referring to the [support diagrams](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.Ubuntu_Kernel_Release_Schedule), they're all vTBD for kernel version past the end of 2018.  As far as I see it's the only place on the page that would show the version per each point release.

Comment: *version To Be Decided* ; if you check the edits the graphic was added before those point releases were in *final* development (later edits have just been text relating to the primarily different GA/HWE defaults for Ubuntu Desktop for 20.04 LTS)